# Azure DevOps Yaml get time and add hours

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I am defining the current time in the variables.

```
variables:
      CurrentTime: $(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
      StartTime: $(CurrentTime).addHours(12)
```

For StartTime variable I'm trying to add 12 hours to the CurrentTime? Does anyone know the right syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do it in an in-line script and output a variable.

i.e.

```
- script: |
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TwelveHoursFromNow]((Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss).AddHours(12))"
```

Will create a variable that can be referenced as `$(TwelveHoursFromNow)`